# C - fscanf - Can you move the file pointer forward?

Tags: c

Currently in my program, I use fscanf to read the file up until it reaches a | symbol. This is posing an issue since when it reaches the first |, it does not move forward. Am I able to move the pointer one position forward?

Here is the code I am using:

```
fscanf(reader, "%d[^|]", &record1[0].CustomerID);
printf("%d \n", record1[0].CustomerID);
fscanf(reader, "%99[^|]", record1[0].domain);
printf("%s \n", record1[0].domain);
fscanf(reader, "%99[^\n]", record1[0].timestamp);
printf("%s \n", record1[0].timestamp);
```

The information is separated in the file as such:

31|www.facebook.com|2015-10-15 12:13:02

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check out fseek() fucntion.

Comment: [fseek()](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html) function.

Comment: What is `"%d[^|]"`?

Comment: @Oleksandr Kravchuk: `fseek` cannot be used for positioning in text streams. In text streams `fseek` can only position to the result of previous `ftell`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `%[]` is a self-sufficient format can only read strings. Your `"%d[^|]"` in the very first `fscanf` does not stand for "read an integer until a `|` symbol", as you probably wanted it to. The `%d` format itself will stop at `|`, since `|` character is not a valid part of integer representation.

Secondly, in the rest of the cases you can just perform a non-assigning read of the character you bumped into

```
fscanf(reader, "%99[^|]%*c", record1[0].domain);
```

That will skip that character and move the file pointer 1 character forward.

Or, alternatively, if your format is so strict, you can write such `fscanf`'s as

```
fscanf(reader, "%99[^|]|", record1[0].domain);
```

In this case the very first `fscanf` can be written as

```
fscanf(reader, "%d|", &record1[0].CustomerID);
```

But keep in mind that `%[]` format cannot read empty strings. When `%[]` format does not match a single input character, it *fails* instead of reading an empty string.

Quirks like that, among other things, is the reason it is preferable to use `fgets` and then parse the string manually.

Comment: Ah right I see, thank you for the information! I'm still finding using the line you provided that the fscanf is not reading the string after the initial |. It simply retains its original value. Is this not because it is not moving past the first |?

Comment: @Thomas Millward: Maybe. (I don't see your code). The first `fscanf` (and the rest of them as well), can be written as `fscanf(reader, "%d|", &record1[0].CustomerID);`. That should move it pas that `|`.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thank you!!